# Integrate Azure Resource Manager (RM) VM with classic networking

Tags: azure-virtual-network

I have a classic network setup in Azure, complete with VMs, vnets and site to site VPN.

I need to introduce a RM VM to integrate with this network. Are there any special considerations I need to make to ensure that the RM VM can integrate with the classic network?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do is to create a Vnet-Vnet connection between the ASM (Azure service manager or classic) and the ARM network. You can do this by creating a gateway and connect them . The only consideration is to use non overlapping subnets. The same consideration you have when creating a vpn between on-premise and Azure.